# Не отображаются картинки в reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не отображаються картинки в reactJS раньше все было нормально проблема появилась 2 дня назад.
С сервера все грузит, но не отображаються и так во всех проектах
простой пример import './App.css';

function App() {
return (

[image]

);
}

export default App;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.pixabay.com%2Fphoto%2F2015%2F04%2F23%2F22%2F00%2Ftree-736885__480.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fimages%2Fsearch%2Fhills%2F&tbnid=L8xfQakH9a8tJM&vet=12ahUKEwi01veLq7PyAhVZB3cKHaY9DHcQMygAegUIARCyAQ..i&docid=E6IaZbhLwoZyCM&w=771&h=480&q=images&ved=2ahUKEwi01veLq7PyAhVZB3cKHaY9DHcQMygAegUIARCyAQ" alt="logo" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: `src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"`

Comment: так в чем все таки проблема ?

Comment: @Mayrbek потому что это ссылка на сайт, а не на изображения